# Weight Paint only Upward Faces

Tags: weight-painting

Can I somehow accurately only apply weight paint on faces pointing upwards?

Answer (score 2):

In edit mode select the faces you want to modify and then, in weight paint mode, enable the faces or vertices selection masking button. Remember that weight is a property of a vertex relatively to a vertex group, so face normal is not taken into account.

[image]

Comment: Thx for the answer! Does that mean I cant spawn particles based on the direction of the normals?

Comment: In the particle panel there are some controls that let you take into account the face normals, while wheight controls only density of the spawn and some hair controls (like lenght or clump). Search for the "velocity" tab, "normal" and "tangent" controls.